# spamassassin how to remove explanation and score breakdown in the message?

Tags: spam, spamassassin

I have setup SpamAssassin in Windows (using the JamSoftware), created a service for spamd.exe and currently SpamAssassin works fine. However, I would like to disable the explanation that SpamAssassin gives on top of the SPAM Message that starts with:

```
Spam detection software, running on the system "mail.example.com",
has identified this incoming email as possible spam.  The original
message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
postmaster@example.com for details.
```

What is the command line parameter or configuration setting that can disable that?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in your local.cf:

```
report_safe 0
```

The spam information will still be available in the header, but it 
will not change the body of the email.